# Combining first elements of nested lists and summing the second elements

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
list = [["r", 200], ["c,", 0.22], ["r", 5000]]
```

How can I combine the tuples with the same first item so that the result is like this:

```
list = [["r", 5200], ["c", 0.22]]
```

Is there some sophisticated way of doing this? The order of tuples doesn't matter.

Thanks

Comment: You have a list of lists there by the way, not a list of tuples :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With use of built-in functions:

```
lst = [["r", 200], ["c,", 0.22], ["r", 5000]]
res={}
for k,v in lst:
  res[k]=res.get(k, 0) + v
res
# {'r': 5200, 'c,': 0.22}
```

To get the result in the original type:

```
[[k, v] for k,v in res.iteritems()]
# [['r', 5200], ['c,', 0.22]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> t = [["r", 200], ["c,", 0.22], ["r", 5000]]
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i, j in t:
...     d[i] += j
... 
>>> print d.items()
[('r', 5200), ('c,', 0.22)]
```

By the way, don't name a list `list`. It will override the built-in type.